# Amazon RDS timeout with php pdf

Tags: php, pdo, amazon-rds, lumen

I'm having a bit of an issue with connecting to my Amamzon RDS (Mysql) instance through a fresh Lumen installation on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The Lumen installation uses the PDO class.

**The problem:**
I can't connect to my RDS, I'm simply getting a timeout when trying:
`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out`

What have i tried?

- I've tried connecting directly to the ip of my rds instance. Same result.
- When debugging my connection, I get a connection string like `mysql:host=x.x.x.x;port=3306;dbname=(...)` - ip and db are correct. Username and password are also correct when debugging the connection.
- Connecting from another server, that is outside Amazon AWS. Also using PDO = negative result
- Checking that the RDS is set up to available from the outside = It is, I can connect from my own computer. Tested with two different machines.
- Looking through various posts about rds and timeouts = no usable solutions
- Connected directly to the ip of my RDS instance = negative result
- When developing on my local machine, I'm not having any problems connecting to the same rds.

Anything else you should know?

- When connecting from my computers (using Sequel Pro), i can connect - I've tried from two computers, both with positive result. This is indifferent if i use the domain/endpoint of the rds instance or connect directly to the ip.

By my own logic,  I should be ablet to connect from any EC2 instance, since I can connect from my own computer.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually give the right permission inbound to RDS from that EC2 Instance?
 You need to modify your security group to give access.

Comment: You got me in the right direction! It turned out that my RDS security group was set up to only accept connections from my ip (both my test-machines were on the same network). It has now been expanded to also allow connections from the EC2 instance ip.

Comment: Good to hear that! My advice is if you have AWS and you want to get isolated and you wanna set the best practices you need to create a VPC with subnets when you create a new resource on AWS you can attach the security group to the inbound rules without use IP just for internal resource.